# Append html content to an iframe in Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom, iframe

I am trying to create a preview of a full fledged html document, meaning this html content is itself a complete html document with `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` tags.

If I would just load that html document into my existing html root, then all styles will be overridden by the ones defined in the newly included html doc. If I include this html document with an iframe over src (`<ifram e src="path/to/doc.html">`) then it works. However, this doc.html is a template where I need to replace certain parts which I have annotated with custom tags. I am doing this by executing the following code

```
$.get('template/template.html', function (template) {

    String.prototype.format = function () {
        var args = arguments;
        this.unkeyed_index = 0;
        return this.replace(/\{(\w*)\}/g, function (match, key) {
            if (key === '') {
                key = this.unkeyed_index;
                this.unkeyed_index++
            }
            if (key == +key) {
                return args[key] !== 'undefined'
                    ? args[key]
                    : match;
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    if (typeof args[i] === 'object' && typeof args[i][key] !== 'undefined') {
                        return args[i][key];
                    }
                }
                return match;
            }
        }.bind(this));
    };

    var renderedHtml = template.format({hello: "hey there"});
});
```

So far this works fine. In the variable `renderedHtml` I have my complete html document and the placeholders are being replaced (in this case the placeholder hello is being replaced with "hey there".

No I have the following html snippet

```
<iframe id="test"></iframe>
```

and I tried the following code:

```
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = renderedHtml;
  document.getElementById('test').appendChild(elem);
  $compile(elem)($scope);
```

Unfortunately, nothing changes on the view. However, if I call `appendChild(elem)` on `document.body` then it works. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

P.S. I know that you should not do DOM manipulations in your angular controller and instead of $compile you should do it with a directive. However, if this way works then I am happy to try to refactor it to a directive :).

Answer (score 9):

I had to do something similar to what you're doing. I needed to make an editor for some HTML templates. The templates didn't preview well due to the CSS in the existing site, so I thought to display the template in an iframe.

I was able to make an angular directive with a watch in it which would update: `iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML` and got me my desired effect. I believe you would be able to intercept the content here and make any replacements for placeholders inside your template as well.

The *preview* directive below should help you on your way, if you still need it after all this time.

```js
var app = angular.module('App',[]);

app.controller("Cont", function($scope){
  $scope.content = "Hi there!";
});

app.directive("preview", function () {
  function link(scope, element) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var element0 = element[0];
    element0.appendChild(iframe);
    var body = iframe.contentDocument.body;

    scope.$watch('content', function () {
      body.innerHTML = scope.content;
    });
  }

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      content: '='
    }
  };
});
```

```css
input, iframe {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 100px;
}
preview iframe {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Cont">
  <input ng-model="content" type="text" /><br />
  <preview content="content"></preview>
</div>
```

Comment: why do we need this piece of code in the directive
**
content: '='
**

Comment: While a (relatively) old solution, I've used this nicely in my app to display template-rendered content in an iframe.  However, I've just started looking at this in FireFox, and I just get a blank iFrame.  Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: @BrendanGreen check out my solution based on Chris's that will work in firefox as well

Answer (score 0):

The updated solution based on Chris's solution for people having issues with Firefox browser:

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);

app.controller("Cont", function($scope){
  $scope.content = "Hi there!";
});

app.directive("preview", function () {
  function link(scope, element) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var element0 = element[0];
    element0.appendChild(iframe);

    scope.$watch('content', function () {
      iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
      iframe.contentWindow.document.write(scope.content);
      iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
    });
  }

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      content: '='
    }
  };
});
```