# Render ckeditor html without editor

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor control for editing html content, then save it. When I finished editing, the ckeditor is hidden and html is rendered in a div. Depending if user can edit or not html, the ckeditor is available or not.

So, the problem is, the css of my webpage is applied to the rendered html. I want the html in my div the same style of when I edit it with ckeditor. Not not the opposite (I don't want to apply my own style to ckeditor).

Can someone help me ?

Edit:
The only thing that look like something that can work is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859577/2111754)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside CKEditor folder, you'll find `contents.css`. You can use it to have the same style as CKEditor.

1. Load `contents.css` in your webpage.
2. Create a wrapping `<div>` outside
   CKEditor html data and give it a class of `.cke_editable` to use the
   CSS rules of `contents.css`.
3. Make sure not to override any CSS rule
   of `contents.css`.

EDIT: Another solution would be:

1. Make a copy of `contents.css`, so as to use it separately.
2. Move all of `body` rules to `.cke_editable` rules (put them above the existing `.cke_editable` rules) and delete `body` section.
3. Prefix every other rule with `.cke_editable`, so as to work only with the contents, so `blockquote` becomes `.cke_editable blockquote`.
4. Tweak the margin setting of `.cke_editable` from `20px` to, let's say, `10px`, to account for the `margin` of the `body` of your webpage.

Comment: I already tought about that. But the font styles are in the body style. Also, I don't want to override my body style with the one of ckeditor (Margin for example).